# Copy data based on loop and then paste data on multiple sheets created based on array

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am creating new data which is dependent upon variable x using loop, then trying to copy the data with each iteration in X and then pasting the data on multiple sheets (variable "FundSheetNames"). Here I dont know how to exit from loop FundSheetNames without next i and then again go on to X to copy new data.

```
Sub peer2()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Activate
Dim X As Range, Y As Range
Set X = Sheets("Peer Code").Range("J2:J11")

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim sheet_names As Variant

For Each sheet_Name In Sheets("Peer Code").Range("K2:K3")
For Each Y In X

Set WS = Worksheets(sheet_Name.Text)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Fund").Activate
    Range("F7:F166").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Activate
    Y.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Range("N2:N161").Select
    Selection.Copy


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Fund").Activate
    Range("F7").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("$F7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
     SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

    With Sheets("Peer Fund")
        Set FOUNDRANGE = .Columns("F:F").Find("*", After:=.Range("F167"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not FOUNDRANGE Is Nothing Then LR1 = FOUNDRANGE.Row
    End With
    Range("F166:F" & LR1 + 1).EntireRow.Select
    Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

        Range("A6:W" & LR1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Peer Fund").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Peer Fund").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
    :=Range("A2:A" & LR1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Peer Fund").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A6:W" & LR1)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    Range("F7").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("A5:W172").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    WS.Activate
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
          With WS
              Set FOUNDRANGE = .Columns("F:F").Find("*", 
              After:=.Range("F167"), 
              searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
              If Not FOUNDRANGE Is Nothing Then LR2 = FOUNDRANGE.Row
        End With
    Range("F166:F" & LR1 + 1).EntireRow.Select
    Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("F7").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Next Y
Next sheet_Name
```

End Sub

Comment: Use `Exit For` when a condition is met (you had enough of looping).

Comment: Can you please help me with how the new entire code would be with your suggested changes

Comment: You will have to either explain what your code is supposed to do or better post the rest of the code. Do [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62099493/edit) your question.

Comment: @vbasic2008 I have put the rest of code .could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

### Exit For

Open a new worksheet and put the code into a module. Then put in some values into column `A`. **Put a few `5`-s among the values**.

The following is an example that looks for the value `5` in column `A`. When `5` is found it returns a message containing the address of the cell where it was found, in the `Immediate window` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

```
Option Explicit

Sub FirstOccurrence()

    Const Col As Variant = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Criteria As Long = 5

    Dim rng As Range
    ' Define the last non-empty cell.
    Set rng = Columns(Col).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    ' Define the column range from FirstRow to row of last non-empty cell.
    Set rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, Col), rng)

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then
            Debug.Print "Cell '" & cel.Address & "' contains the value '" _
              & Criteria & "'."
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

You have just seen how the code finds just the first occurrence of `5`.

Now remove the line `Exit For` and see the results in the `Immediate window` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).